# Java two collections contains any

Tags: java, collections

Java two collections contains any

Large two collections A and B contain best best approach in these

1) Collections.disjoint(A, B)

2) org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils

CollectionUtils.containsAny(A,B)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their respective source codes, it looks like `Collections.disjoint` is smarter about when its arguments are `Set`s and have fast `contains` implementations, and `CollectionUtils` is a little smarter about checking if either collection is empty, but that's generally a smaller win.

Based on that, I'd use `Collections.disjoint`, which I'd tend to do anyway  just because it's built-in.